# Need to get Filepath of an external process using processId in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, process, filepath

Using the following code, I can do a loop and get the ProcessId and process name.

```
For Each mo In MgmtClass.GetInstances
```

What I really need is the file path to the process. And I don't want to start an executable to get the path.

Any help is appreciated...
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the ProcessId, you can use System.Process to then get the file path of the executing process.

Given you have a variable called processId -

```
'Imports System.Diagnostics

Dim proc = Process.GetProcessById(processId)

MessageBox.Show(proc.Modules(0).FileName)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I get an "access denied" error on every file? Maybe it's my fault, not sure. Here's the code I'm using. Maybe you can tell me where I'm going wrong     Dim pID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(mo("ProcessId"))
            Dim proc = Process.GetProcessById(pID)

            Try
                str = proc.Modules(0).FileName
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try

Comment: Sorry about the code not being in the code box. Sometimes I just can't get it to work... I should probably say that it's the proc.Modules(0).FileName is where I get the "access denied" error...

Comment: No problem, its not as simple as running visual studio as administrator is it? The code that I supplied and tested works on my local machine. Can you try `Dim proc = Process.GetProcessById(Process.GetProcesses()(0).Id)` on your machine this will just get the first running process that the system can find.

Comment: Thanks man... I tried your idea and this is what proc is:      {System.Diagnostics.Process (UninstallMonitor)} How can I use this to find the path to the program? Again, thanks

Comment: Forgot to address your comment about it not being easy... And no, it's not. I've been trying to find a solution for this for a long time!

Comment: YAC (yet another comment) How in the world did you get it to work on your machine. The whole world gets the "access denied" error. You can Google it and see :)

Comment: OK so my scenario is, I am running VS as administrator to prevent any permission access to files. I am also a local admin on my machine, removing similar issues.

Comment: OK so my scenario is, I am running VS as administrator to prevent any permission access to files. I am also a local admin on my machine, removing similar issues. Running the following code in VS - `Process.GetProcessById(Process.GetProcesses()(0).Id).Modules(0).FileName` gives the desired result. I also set the prefer 32 bit on my compile settings for the project to false.